# how to execute code after pass by controller?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How can I execute code after request pass by a controller? I've tried to terminate  my controller's code  with: res.content = 'something'; next(); , but I think I'm limited to use functions as middle-ware just if I use router.use, but it doesn't work for me.
is there some way to execute code after it pass by a controller? of course I can create a method and call it whenever I need, but I'm just curious about it.
The reason why I'm doing it is: refresh token whenever an operation is successfully done and change my response to: { token: 'aaaaabbb123123' , payload: 'my real response'}

Comment: Please describe to problem you're trying to solve (don't fall for the [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/) trap) and post relevant code, best formatted in a readable way.

Comment: You can create a service that accepts payload and re-structure it with the refreshed token.